# Invalid API key Kudan Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kudan

I am trying to implement Augmented Reality application Using Kudan framework on Android Studio.
 
I have followed the starting tutorial [here](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Getting_started) and also named my application id and package "eu.kudan.ar" as suggested [here](https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys) in order to use the correspoding API key.
 But when i run the application, the marker is not being detected and in the Log the message **"Your API Key is not valid"** is shown.
does anyone know how to solve this problem please?

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using? If it's 1.4, then you have to use the really long key rather than one of the smaller ones. Also, be sure you've copied the _whole_ key, because it is very long.

Comment: Thank you! that was my bad, i didn't see the hint in the bottom of the page where they talked about version 1.4. Now works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Use this key

```
key.setAPIKey("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");
```

ANd change package name to  `eu.kudan.ar`